# Graphics issue OS X Mavericks

Tags: macos, mac, graphics-card, gpu, osx-mavericks

Sorry for my english in advance.
I have Macbook Air 13" (mid 2012) [CPU: Core i5 with GPU: HD 4000].
I am facing problems with the GPU. First after. I could not boot after updated to OS X Mavericks (10.9.1) .
It's hangs on Grey screen with Apple's logo and spinning loading gray wheel.
After two days, I was able to to boot it but GPU not working correctly.
In  Graphics section on Hardware,  there is no text for OpenGL and QE. 
In Launchpad,  icons blinks when I scrolling. Cannot open 3d applications (application crash).

Do anyone face the same problem ? Anybody know to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have
A) hardware issues.
B) a partially failed upgrade to Mavericks.

First run the hardware diagnostics. You can get into those from the startup-screen without actually having to boot into OSX.
(Exact instructions are on the Apple web-site.)
That would show if A) is the problem.

As for B):
I would recommend to wipe the MacBook and to re-install fresh. (I hope you have a good Time-machine backup...)
That should solve B).
You would need to make a USB install medium first. Instructions on how to do that you cna find on the Apple web-site too.

Comment: I run Apple Hardware Test (Quick test) and failed with error: 4SNS/1/C0000008:TPCD–124. I check on internet and it's look like some temperature sensor.

Comment: That would, most likely, indicate some sort of cooling problem. You best contact Apple Customer support. Hope your laptop is still under warranty.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not under warranty anymore. Will enjoy it so only to develop. Downloaded application for temperature. CPU running 40-50 and max to 70C without watching videos or playing games. Is this normal?

Comment: @JorniaKabakum As I don't have a MacBook I can't judge if that is normal or not.